# Jira Rest Java Client: "403 Forbidden" error

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api

I've been trying to connect to the Jira server (with basic auth) for several days now, but I can't get it to work. I always get a "403 Forbidden" error. In the meantime I am desperately despairing and hope that someone can help me.

The sample code looks like this:

```
public class Main
{
    private static final String JIRA_URL = "https://jira.mycompany.com/rest/api/latest/project/";
    private static String auth = new String(Base64.encode("admin" + ":" + "password"));
    private static String headerAuthorization = "Authorization";
    final static String headerAuthorizationValue = "Basic " + auth;
    final static String headerType = "application/json";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Client client = Client.create();
        WebResource webResource = client.resource(JIRA_URL);

        ClientResponse response = webResource.header(headerAuthorization,headerAuthorizationValue).type(headerType).accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);

        int statusCode = response.getStatus();
        if (statusCode == 401) {
            throw new AuthenticationException("401 Invalid Username or Password");
            } else if (statusCode == 403) {
                throw new AuthenticationException("403 Forbidden");
                }
    }

}
```

As already written, I always get a 403 error. :( If I enter the URL in the browser, it works without problems, so I am absolutely at a loss. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks a lot for your help!

**Edit 2020-05-03**

As suggested by PiRocks, I once tried to compare the calls.

**Browser call:**
[image]

Header:
[image]

It looks the same to me, but unfortunately I don't know many details in the header. Are there differences to my code?

**Postman:**
Additionally I tried to make a request with Postman. That works, too.
Authorization type is also "Basic Auth".
[image]

As you can see I got a 200 status code and everything worked. In my opinion the request is identical to my code, isn't it?

Additionally I tried the code from Postman, but strangely enough I get the 403 error even with this code.
[image]

Does anyone else have any ideas? I'm running out of things to think of what could be wrong... :(

Comment: Try logging the requests made by the browser and compare

Comment: Hi PiRocks, thanks for your input! I have added some more information to my post after I tried the calls in the browser and Postman. Do you still have an idea where the problem might be?

Comment: May you provide the original exception? I guess that you have to add your company certification to the JRE Keystore. Try to execute steps under 'Obtain and import the endpoint's public certificate' from here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/if-you-use-self-signed-certificates-938028692.html

Comment: Unfortunately there is no real exception. All I get is: "GET https://jira.mycompany.com/rest/api/latest/project/ returned a response status of 403" Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.AuthenticationException: 403 Forbidden at jira.Main.main(Main.java:70)... Does that help?

Comment: Additionally I added the company certification to the JRE Keystore but unfortunately without success. I still getting the 403 error... Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. I had to set a proxy although I was connected to the company network via VPN:

```
System.getProperties().put("https.proxyHost", proxyHost);
System.getProperties().put("https.proxyPort", proxyPort);
System.getProperties().put("https.proxyUser", proxyUser);
System.getProperties().put("https.proxyPassword", proxyPassword);
System.getProperties().put("https.proxySet", "true");
```

Now everything works. This stupid simple mistake has cost me a lot of days...